# Calculate GPS location with center point

Tags: algorithm, gps, geometry

I got one center point GPS such as(32.112342,112.223123)

and I got radius 10(km)

I can draw a circle with these information

Here I have one new requirement

I need fix this circle with little Hexagon.

and the center Hexagon must be the the center of the circle

how can I get all those little Hexagon's center point GPS location

Thans

Comment: What did you try? With what you tried, what specific problems do you face?

Answer (score 0):

Suggest you to try with Graphics2D as provided in java.awt package.
You can use its drawPolygon() and fillPolygon() methods.